# RabbiMQ stomp auto delete queue - Precondition failed

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp, spring-rabbit

I am writing application that uses STOMP for communication.
Server side is written using Spring Boot 2.1.7 and as external broker RabbitMQ 3.7.1 is used. On client side, I am using StompJS.

When client subscribes to user destination, eg. `/user/queue/some-queue` Spring will map it to `/queue/some-queue-{sessionID}` and RabbitMQ creates queue with corresponding name.

On subscription I added header `{'auto-delete': true}`, as specified here [RabbitMQ Stomp Docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html#queue-parameters), and that created auto delete queue in RabbitMQ.

Problem comes when I try sending message to user as

```
simpTemplate.convertAndSendToUser('user', '/queue/some-queue', message)
```

Spring correctly translated queue name, but rabbitmq responds with error

```
PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'auto_delete' for queue
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Any chance to have a simple project from you to play with?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I will create one and share it. Thank you.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Hi, I created simple project [link](https://github.com/borist2/spring-rabbimq-test-queue). I added most basic security and similar. The received problem is same. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, would you mind to share some instruction or test how to reproduce the issue? Looks like I need to do a lot of work to make the client connected to that server to make it fail.

Comment: Of course, sorry. I added Readme file with instructions.

Comment: Yeah... Now I can reproduce it. Doesn't look like there is something wrong from Spring side. All the queues and subscriptions are handled in the STOMP plugin of RabbitMQ. Since this precondition has failed from there some how, only the place to investigate is that STOMP plugin. Please, consider to raise such a question in RabbitMQ user group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. If I add same same headers, which were defined during subscription, when sending message, it will work correctly.

On example it looks like this:

```
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("auto-delete", "true");
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("some-user", "/queue/some-queue", "Test payload", headers);
```